# eigenvalue sign of $M - \lambda_{k} I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a symmetric  $n\times n$ tri-diagonal matrix, with positive values in its main diagonal. and let $\mathbf{1} \in R^n$  be the vector of all 1, such
$M \mathbf{1} = 0$

Suppose $M$ has eigenvalues $0=\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$, and let $\mathbf{v}_k$ be an eigenvector of $\lambda_{k}$, the corresponding $k$-th eigenvalue of $M$ with multiplicity 1.

Why $(M - \lambda_{k} I)$ has $k - 1$ negative eigenvalues?

Comment: En inglés, sólo se usa el signo de interrogación derecho.

Comment: Actually, Richard Guy uses the double question mark notation, which he says he borrowed from "the Hungarians", though he uses it for a conjectural or hypothetical statement.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $\lambda-\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $M-\lambda_kI$.

Comment: is  "If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $\lambda-lambda_k$  is an eigenvalue of $M-\lambda_k I$"
Because of this?

\begin{align}
M \mathbf{x}_j &= \lambda_j \mathbf{x}_j \\
M \mathbf{x}_j - \lambda_k I \mathbf{x}_j  &= \lambda_j \mathbf{x}_j - \lambda_k I \mathbf{x}_j \\
M \mathbf{x}_j - \lambda_k I \mathbf{x}_j  &= \lambda_j \mathbf{x}_j - \lambda_k \mathbf{x}_j \\
(M - \lambda_k I) \mathbf{x}_j = (\lambda_j - \lambda_k) \mathbf{x}_j
\end{align}

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$